# PWA User Logon Account changed after changing to Forms and Windows Authentication

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, project-server, windows-authentication

So I'm in a bit of a pickle. In order to get OWA to work on our external, customer site we enabled forms and windows authentication on our internal site and added a custom login so users were prompted for their AD credentials. That is working fine now with FBA users able to view and edit office documents just fine.

The problem is now in Project Web App. All user accounts changed from a Logon Account like **i:0#.w|domain\username** to **i:0.w|fbamembershipprovider\username** and when a user logs in (I'm assuming) another entry with the original Logon Account name is created in the table.

The problem with this is that all the tasks assigned to users are now gone. What did we do wrong? How do I revert all those users with the new fbamembershipprovider account names to the old user logon account names?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem since 2-3 weeks! Changed our SharePoint and Project Server 2013 installation from NTLM based Authentication to NTLM+Form based authentication and now the Project Server active directory synchronization changes all Logon Accounts from the Project Server users from **i:0#.w|domain\username** to **i:0.w|fbamembershipprovider\username**!

As a temporary workaround I deactivated the Active Directory synchronization in Project Server and changed all user accounts in Project Server back to the correct Logon Account format: **i:0#.w|domain\username** and deleted the falsly, newly and duplicate created user accounts.
That was manually work...

Does anybody have a tip or solution for us how to solve this?

Comment: I didn't really have a solution, but when I removed the Forms Authentication all accounts were switched back to the domain login account name on the next sync. A solution that involved us being able to have both enabled would be awesome.